# Responsive Video Window resize (possible js / jquery conflict)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, resize

I have a module wherein a user can select which video file to play for the smartphone, tablet and desktop. Let's say the user uploads three different videos.

When you go to the site(local) it loads the appropiate file according to screen size so the document ready code is working. But when you manually resize the browser window it should listen to the code in the .resize event.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

if (viewportWidth < 767) {
  document.write('video');
} else if (viewportWidth < 979) {
  document.write('video');
} else if (viewportWidth > 980){
  document.write('video');
}
}());   

$(window).resize(function() {

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

if (viewportWidth < 767) {
  document.write('video');
} else if (viewportWidth < 979) {
  document.write('video');
} else if (viewportWidth > 980){
  document.write('video');
}
}());   
</script>
```

So I probably messed up the coding ;-)... And I believe it could be even shorter by on resize activate doc. ready function. I removed the very long code sections in the `doc.write` and just filled in 'video' because the codes in there where not relevant and would only add to confusion. I know this code is not showing a video as is.

I already tried numerous SO ideas and from other Google Result pages. But none seems to work. Even tried a code from back in the day which did do the video but it disabled other native CMS functions so deleted that one.

**The Question:**

**How to make the below code execute every time the browser window is resized?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

if (viewportWidth < 767) {
  document.write('video');
} else if (viewportWidth < 979) {
  document.write('video');
} else if (viewportWidth > 980){
  document.write('video');
}
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)() 
Here is a fiddle with the resize working: https://jsfiddle.net/b6fncgwg/

The key is using .html() to change the html of your background/video div.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    changeBackground();
});

changeBackground();

function changeBackground(){
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

    if (viewportWidth < 767) {
        $("#video-bg").html('<video autoplay nomuted loop preload="none" poster="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/small.jpg" id="bgvid-SMARTPHONE"><source type="video/mp4" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/small.mp4"><source type="video/webm" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/small.webm"><source type="video/ogg" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/small.ogv">');
    } else if (viewportWidth < 979) {
       $("#video-bg").html('<video autoplay nomuted loop preload="none" poster="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.jpg" id="bgvid-TABLET"><source type="video/mp4" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4"><source type="video/webm" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.webm"><source type="video/ogg" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.ogv"></video>  <!--    Buttons or metadata go here -->');
    } else if (viewportWidth > 980) {
       $("#video-bg").html('<video autoplay nomuted loop preload="none" poster="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/jaguar_video1.jpg" id="bgvid-DESKTOP"><source type="video/mp4" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/jaguar_video1.mp4"><source type="video/webm" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/jaguar_video1.webm"><source type="video/ogg" src="http://research.loginsecuretest.eu/loginsecurecmp/background//images/clientvideos/jaguar_video1.ogv"></video>  <!--    Buttons or metadata go here');
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same code as I posted with the only exception the two spaces by the word window and the () at the end. Anyway it did not work. But thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: I changed it a little bit. You have some gaps in your > and < checks and I think writing to the whole document destroys the scripts after the first call so I logged them instead.

Comment: I have tried it and it is so strange. It should work. But it isn't can there be a conflict between the doc ready code and this. Is there a way to combine the two. Maybe that solves it. I am going to see If I can get a life site online.

Comment: Yes but that is going to take a whole lot of time. I am now uploading to a testserver. That is quicker. Thank you very much for helping. Maybe it is a localhost conflict. Don't think so but you never know.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you just trying to have a responsive video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79550/discussion-between-purple11111-and-chizzle).